# How to convert Array to HashMap in Java with Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I was trying to something pretty simple, but it fails on compilation, and I can't understand who

I have a list of headers, I need to convert it to
`Map<Index, String>` meaning the key (index) and the value is the header name

I know how to make it with for each, but I want to have it in `Collectors.to` map
any help would be appreciated

```
final String[] headerDisplayName = getHeaderDisplayName(harmonizationComponentDataFixRequest);

IntStream.of(0, headerDisplayName.length).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), index-> headerDisplayName[index]));
```

Comment: `IntStream` doesn't have a `#collect(Collector)` method.

Comment: check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319231/java-8-listt-into-mapt-index)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `range` method in combination with `boxed` method of `IntStream`.

(When you use the `of` method like in your example, only 0 and the size of the array are in this stream. In addition this would lead to an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`)

A possible solution would look like this (first parameter of the `range` method is included, the second parameter is excluded)

```java
Map<Integer, String> map = IntStream.range(0, headerDisplayName.length)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(), 
                i -> headerDisplayName[i])
        );
```

Comment: To know the reason behind why `boxed()` solved this, check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67800492/2346131) for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the @csalmhof's answer, I think it's to explain here why using `boxed` is working.

If  you don't use `boxed()` method and simply write the following:

```java
Map<Integer, String> map = IntStream.range(0, headerDisplayName.length)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(),
                index -> headerDisplayName[index])
        );
```

Java will have to take `index` as of type `Object` and there's no implicit conversion that can happen and so you'll get error.

But if you put `boxed()` like in the following code, you won't get error:

```java
Map<Integer, String> map = IntStream.range(0, headerDisplayName.length)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(),
                index -> headerDisplayName[index])
        );
```

you're not getting error here because java interprets `index` as an `Integer` and there's implicit casting happening from `Integer` to `int`.

A good IDE can help you with this type of explanation. In IntelliJ if you press `ctrl` + `space` after keeping your cursor on `index` (with Eclipse key-map enabled) you will get the following without `boxed()`.

[image]

And this is what you get when you've `boxed()` placed.
[image]

I hope this clarifies why using boxed() is saving you from compilation error. Also, you can use this thing in future to find actual type of parameter in lambda which can be helpful in case cases (one of the case is the one that OP pointed out)

Comment: @BarakKedem The fundamental error is that there is no such `IntStream#collect(Collector)` method. There is, however, a `Stream#collect(Collector)` method and that's why calling `IntStream#boxed()` works, because it returns a `Stream<Integer>`. The IDE error shown in this answer is "confused", probably by the fact that the `IntStream#collect(Supplier,ObjIntConsumer,BiConsumer)` method exists. So the compiler sees there is indeed a method named `collect` and moves on to trying to parse the argument passed to the method. But since you're creating a `Collector` there's a problem and it ...

Comment: ... can't infer the generic types. So it defaults to `Object` for `toMap` which means it infers the argument(s) to be a `Function<Object, Object>`. That makes `index` an `Object` and thus the error when trying to use it to access an array element. But if you were to simply change `index -> headerDisplayName[index]` to `(Integer index) -> headerDisplayName[index]` that part of the code would start working. And then you would see that the underlying error is trying to pass a `Collector` to the `IntStream#collect(Supplier,ObjIntStream,BiConsumer)` method.